# Activity name not showing in Google Analytics active screen name in Android

Tags: android, google-analytics

I have many activities in my app. I am setting screen name for all the activities in a xml file. But in Google Analytics active screen name not showing

what is problem my code is below please help me some one

### AnalyticsTrackers:-

```
public final class AnalyticsTrackers {

    public enum Target {
        APP,
        // Add more trackers here if you need, and update the code in #get(Target) below
    }

    private static AnalyticsTrackers sInstance;

    public static synchronized void initialize(Context context) {
        if (sInstance != null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Extra call to initialize analytics trackers");
        }

        sInstance = new AnalyticsTrackers(context);
    }

    public static synchronized AnalyticsTrackers getInstance() {
        if (sInstance == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Call initialize() before getInstance()");
        }

        return sInstance;
    }

    private final Map<Target, Tracker> mTrackers = new HashMap<Target, Tracker>();
    private final Context mContext;

    /**
     * Don't instantiate directly - use {@link #getInstance()} instead.
     */
    private AnalyticsTrackers(Context context) {
        mContext = context.getApplicationContext();
    }

    public synchronized Tracker get(Target target) {
        if (!mTrackers.containsKey(target)) {
            Tracker tracker;
            switch (target) {
                case APP:
                    tracker = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(mContext).newTracker(R.xml.app_tracker);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unhandled analytics target " + target);
            }
            mTrackers.put(target, tracker);
        }

        return mTrackers.get(target);
    }
}
```

### MyApplication:-

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    public static final String TAG = MyApplication.class
            .getSimpleName();

    private static MyApplication mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;

        AnalyticsTrackers.initialize(this);
        AnalyticsTrackers.getInstance().get(AnalyticsTrackers.Target.APP);
    }

    public static synchronized MyApplication getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public synchronized Tracker getGoogleAnalyticsTracker() {
        AnalyticsTrackers analyticsTrackers = AnalyticsTrackers.getInstance();
        return analyticsTrackers.get(AnalyticsTrackers.Target.APP);
    }

    /***
     * Tracking screen view
     *
     * @param screenName screen name to be displayed on GA dashboard
     */
    public void trackScreenView(String screenName) {
        Tracker t = getGoogleAnalyticsTracker();

        // Set screen name.
        t.setScreenName(screenName);

        // Send a screen view.
        t.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());

        GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).dispatchLocalHits();
    }

    /***
     * Tracking exception
     *
     * @param e exception to be tracked
     */
    public void trackException(Exception e) {
        if (e != null) {
            Tracker t = getGoogleAnalyticsTracker();

            t.send(new HitBuilders.ExceptionBuilder()
                            .setDescription(
                                    new StandardExceptionParser(this, null)
                                            .getDescription(Thread.currentThread().getName(), e))
                            .setFatal(false)
                            .build()
            );
        }
    }

    /***
     * Tracking event
     *
     * @param category event category
     * @param action   action of the event
     * @param label    label
     */
    public void trackEvent(String category, String action, String label) {
        Tracker t = getGoogleAnalyticsTracker();

        // Build and send an Event.
        t.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder().setCategory(category).setAction(action).setLabel(label).build());

    }
}
```

### MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private Toolbar mToolbar;

    private Button btnSecondScreen, btnSendEvent, btnException, btnAppCrash, btnLoadFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        btnSecondScreen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSecondScreen);
        btnSendEvent = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendEvent);
        btnException = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnException);
        btnAppCrash = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAppCrash);
        btnLoadFragment = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLoadFragment);

        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        /**
         * Launching another activity to track the other screen
         */
        btnSecondScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        /**
         * Event tracking
         * Event(Category, Action, Label)
         */
        btnSendEvent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Tracking Event
                MyApplication.getInstance().trackEvent("Book", "Download", "Send event example");

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Event \'Book\' \'Download\' \'Event example\' is sent. Check it on Google Analytics Dashboard!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        /**
         * Tracking Exception Manually
         * All known exceptions can be tracking this way
         * using Try & Catch
         */
        btnException.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    String name = null;
                    if (name.equals("ravi")) {
                        /* Never comes here as it throws null pointer exception */
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // Tracking exception
                    MyApplication.getInstance().trackException(e);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.toast_track_exception), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });

        /**
         * Tracking App Crashes
         * Manually generation app crash by dividing with zero
         */
        btnAppCrash.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.toast_app_crash), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        int answer = 12 / 0;
                    }
                };

                Handler h = new Handler();
                h.postDelayed(r, 1500);
            }
        });

        /**
         * Tracking Fragment View
         */
        btnLoadFragment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                FooterFragment footerFragment = new FooterFragment();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, footerFragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

### app_tracker.xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- End current session if app sleeps for a period of time -->
    <integer name="ga_sessionTimeout">300</integer>

    <!-- Enable automatic Activity measurement -->
    <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>

    <!--  The property id associated with this analytics tracker -->
    <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-79508091-1</string>

    <string name="ga_sampleFrequency">100.0</string>

    <bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>

    <screenName name="info.androidhive.googleanalytics.activity.MainActivity">Home Screen</screenName>
    <screenName name="info.androidhive.googleanalytics.activity.SecondActivity">Second Screen</screenName>
    <screenName name="info.androidhive.googleanalytics.activity.FooterFragment">Footer Fragment</screenName>

    <!--
      See Project Structure -> Analytics -> Google Analytics -> Learn More
      to learn more about configuring this file.
    -->
</resources>
```

Comment: your code seems to be nice , please use logger and post issue 
adb shell setprop log.tag.GAv4 DEBUG
adb logcat -s GAv4

Answer (score 0):

An XML configuration(app_tracker.xml) as you describe above is used whenever '**ga_autoActivityTracking**' is set to true. This means tracking automatically reports a new screen view whenever an Activity starts.
That's means if you have manually configured/send screen name does not appear on reports. so you must set **ga_autoActivityTracking** to **false**.

```
<!-- off automatic Activity measurement -->
<bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">false</bool>
```